# How repair/uninstall Visual Web Developer 2010 Beta 2?

Tags: uninstall, visual-web-developer

I cannot uninstall Visual Web Developer 2010 Beta 2. When I was trying to uninstall the first time, the power went off to my machine and screwed up the Beta 2 installation. I cannot find a Visual Web Developer 2010 Beta 2 download on the Microsoft website any longer to repair the Beta 2 installation. How can I get VWD 2010 Beta 2 off of my system so I can install the new release?

Comment: I am having a nice little excercise at Microsoft trying to get this solved if anyone wants to follow it. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressinstall/thread/a2f4d9c3-1a78-4ac1-b316-04c5727feb46/

Comment: Here is a link to another person with the same issue:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/550848/express-2010-beta-uninstall-express-2010-install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after weeks of waiting, Microsoft finally came through via Scott Hanselman and Aaron Stebner. Below is a link to Beta 2 versions of the software that would not uninstall correctly for me:

- [Download Visual Studio 2010 Express Editions](http://blogs.msdn.com/danielfe/archive/2009/10/21/download-visual-studio-2010-express-editions.aspx)

You can reinstall Microsoft Express Beta 2 software via the link above and then properly uninstall the software to use the new Microsoft Express Editions.

It's sad that I had to answer my own question here, but that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Link above does not work. I think, because of beta 2 expiration on Jun 30 2010.
I've searched string 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express Beta 2 - ENU' in registry and found key
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\F103BA167E2A518329D6F1EE30551247\InstallProperties
There was a subkey UninstallString, which was 'MsiExec.exe /X{61AB301F-A2E7-3815-926D-1FEE03552174}' for me. I ran this command line from VC Beta2 directory and uninstall was successful.